# How do I split/group a textfile?

Tags: c#, split, text-files

I want to split/group this text:

```
[Help]

Group0

[Help Op]

Group1

[Help Mod]

Group2

[Help Member]

Group3

[Help Default]

Group4
```

How may I do so?
So Like

string op would equal Group1, or whatever text is underneath the tag [Help OP]

same with the other 'tags' like string default would equal 'group4'

or even if there is a better way to lay this out such as xml or whatever else.

Comment: Looks "almost" like an ini file.

Comment: you're looking for ini parser?

Comment: You should edit your original question rather than posting a new one, when you're really not asking anything different.

Comment: Do you have two separate user accounts?

Comment: The other one is unregistered, and I have no clue on how to log into it

Answer (score 2):

If you go with an xml file, you can take advantage of LINQ-TO-XML to handle the parsing operations. If you go with something like an ini file or a custom version like you have, you'll have to write your own parsing code. Not terribly tough, but extra work none the less. Take a look at LINQ-TO-XML if you don't mind working with the angle bracket tax. [Here](http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/introduction-to-linq-simple-xml-parsing) is a tutorial that may get you started.

NOTE: I'm assuming you're working with .Net 3.5 or higher. If that is not the case, working with XML is a bit more work.

UPDATE:

If you're leaning more towards an ini approach, your files will look like this:

[Help]
Op=Group1
Mod=Group2
Member=Group3
Default=Group4

[Some Other section]
someKey=someValue

etc.

I've got a simple library that I wrote that can parse through the ini file, reading keys and values, writing keys and values and saving ini file changes (either to the same location by overwriting or by saving to a new file). The code is too big to post in here, but I could always toss it up somewhere and put a link to it.

To look up a value it would be something like the following:

```
var ini = new IniFile(fileName);

string myValue;

// look up section Help, key Op
if (ini.TryGetValue("Help", "Op", out myValue))
{
    // do something with myValue, which would contain "Group1"
}

// if the result was false, it means the section or the key did not exist.
```

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 Windows external functions defined in kernel32.dll to read/write .ini files.
You need to import them into your code and then use them:

**In VB6 I used to do this:**

```
Declare Function GetPrivateProfileString Lib "kernel32" Alias "GetPrivateProfileStringA" (ByVal lpApplicationName As String, ByVal lpKeyName As Any, ByVal lpDefault As String, ByVal lpReturnedString As String, ByVal nSize As Long, ByVal lpFileName As String) As Long

Declare Function WritePrivateProfileString Lib "kernel32" Alias "WritePrivateProfileStringA" (ByVal lpApplicationName As String, ByVal lpKeyName As Any, ByVal lpString As Any, ByVal lpFileName As String) As Long
```

**In C# you do it like this:**

```
[DllImport("kernel32")]
internal static extern int WritePrivateProfileString(string lpAppName, string lpKeyName, string lpString, string lpFileName);

[DllImport("kernel32")]
internal static extern int GetPrivateProfileString(string lpAppName, string lpKeyName, string lpDefault, string lpReturnedString, int nSize, string lpFileName);
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you want to read the `ini` file with key and data existing in the provided format. So, if you want to read the data from `text file`, you can do

```
const string HELP = "[Help]", HELP_OP = "[Help Op]", HELP_MOD = "[Help Mod]", HELP_MEMBER = "[Help Member]", HELP_DEFAULT = "[Help Default]";
          string [] strConfig = File.ReadAllLines("G:\\Test.txt");
          Dictionary<string, List<string>> myConfigConfig = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();
          string curr = string.Empty;
          foreach (string str in strConfig)
          {
              if (str == string.Empty)
                  continue;
              if (str == HELP || str == HELP_OP || str == HELP_MOD || str == HELP_MEMBER || str == HELP_DEFAULT)
              {
                  myConfigConfig.Add(str, new List<string>());
                  curr = str;  
              }
              else
                  myConfigConfig[curr].Add(str);
          }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
            string s = @"
[Help]

Group0

[Help Op]

Group1

[Help Mod]

Group2

[Help Member]

Group3

[Help Default]

Group4";

            MatchCollection matches = new Regex(@"\[Help ([a-zA-Z]+)\]\s+([^[]+)\s+", RegexOptions.Singleline).Matches(s);

            Dictionary<string, string> result = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            foreach (Match match in matches)
                result[match.Groups[1].Value] = match.Groups[2].Value;

            Console.WriteLine(result["Op"]);
```